# JavaScript: Module architecture suggestions

Tags: javascript

I wanna create a website which will have a left side search filter option panel, to sort through the data on the website.

I am thinking about using revealing module pattern.

But should I simply create a module for each filter options which have there own filter logic -and then create a init module to render all the selected filters?

What is the best module architecture in this situation ? what would you do ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not to sound rude, but this is a problem you really need to consider yourself.  It's not appropriate against SO's question guidelines

Comment: Classic MVC would have a model module that has the data and each filter function would be a transform, either as a seperate module you plug in or as a function inside that model. Then a view module that turns that data into html nodes. And lastly a controller module that will coordinate between the other modules and handle user input, calling the methods on the other modules. The way you make the modules is up to yourself. I personally like revealing module pattern since you can easily keep helper functions private.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use modules for that. Keep it simple.

Just use simple functions that implement the same "interface" (though there is no concept of "interface" in JS unless you use TypeScript or another similar language).

You can also use a library such as [lodash](https://lodash.com/) that will give you a lot a tools to easily define such kinds of functions and to manipulate and compose them.

That is only for the implementation of your filter functions though. Your application is probably a bit more complex than that, so you may want to check out how to structure the code of an application if this is new for you. The [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern is a good start, but for bigger applications there are other architectures that may be more suitable and you will want to use a framework React/Redux or Angular to implement them properly.